# Vagrant not running on 33.33.33.10

Tags: vagrant

The first time I started up vagrant, the VM was running on 33.33.33.10. After a "vagrant destroy", every time I start up vagrant it runs on 127.0.0.1 even though my Vagrantfile has the following configuration:

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"
```

How do I get vagrant to run on 33.33.33.10 again?

Answer (score 2):

127.0.0.1 is loopback interface's home address. Your current machine is always 127.0.0.1.

When you're looking for the proper IP address, run command `ifconfig` (on UNIX), and look for `eth` interface.

I guess it's still running at the same address, you just missed the correct IP.

Would you please try running `ifconfig eth0` on your virtual machine?

HTH.

Comment: I found this q/a based on trying to figure out what `33.33.33.10` was for. `127.0.0.1` seems to work just fine (as well as `localhost` and `127.0.1.1` when I have more than one running). Here is my [`ifconfig eth0`](http://i.imgur.com/3NYnq.png), and the box I'm running (both manifests have been installed separately) can be found here: https://github.com/jakzal/puppet-symfony Should I blow the `33.33.33.10 vagrant.dev` sentence? (As in, I don't know what it's for...?)